# How to show file at in-build Download app in android?

Tags: android

I have downloaded data as byte array from my own server and saved it at the shared download folder of the phone. But this file is not showing at the in-build download app of phone.

How to show file in-build download app?

I am using  the following code for it:

```
Java.IO.File storageDir = global::Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory (global::Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);

Java.IO.File storageFile = new Java.IO.File (storageDir, filename);                 
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes (storageFile.ToString(), filebyte);
```

If possible how can i do it?

Note: `filename` is the name of the file and `filebyte` is the byte array of data.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to download the file via Android's [`DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) in order to make it appear in the Downloads app.

You have to build a DownloadManager.Request, than pass that to `DownloadManager.enqueue()`.

Comment: I don't have uri. instead of it, i have a content of file that are already fetched from my own server. how to build a DownloadManager.Request?